# Cython installation does not find the Python.h file?

Tags: python, cython

I wanted to install cython on my ubuntu 12.04 and I entered in the terminal

```
sudo easy_install cython
```

in response, I get the following error:

```
Searching for cython  
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/cython/  
Reading http://www.cython.org  
Reading http://cython.org  
Best match: Cython 0.16  
Downloading http://www.cython.org/release/Cython-0.16.zip  
Processing Cython-0.16.zip  
Running Cython-0.16/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-VzJ0lH/Cython-0.16/egg-dist-tmp-BMJs3p  
Compiling module Cython.Plex.Scanners ...  
Compiling module Cython.Plex.Actions ...  
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Lexicon ...  
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Scanning ...  
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Parsing ...  
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Visitor ...  
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.FlowControl ...  
Compiling module Cython.Compiler.Code ...  
Compiling module Cython.Runtime.refnanny ...  
warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'  
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'  
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'  
warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'  
warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Utility'  
warning: no files found matching '.cpp' under directory 'Cython/Utility'  
/tmp/easy_install-VzJ0lH/Cython-0.16/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: El fitxer o directori no existeix  
compilation terminated.  
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

sorry for the catalan in here but El fitxer o directori no existeix means that the file doesn't exist

i think that i perhaps miss something or i don't know

does anyone else have the same problem? or know how to install it correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

depending on how you installed python, you may need to get the dev files as well (if you installed with apt-get or Synaptic).

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

or maybe

```
sudo apt-get install python2.6-dev  #substitute your python version here...
```

Note that this is necessary if you need to install any C extensions to Cpython.

Comment: With Ubuntu 12.10 (targeting python2.7.5) I was finally(!) able to get this err to go away by specifying "sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev"  I had been trying just python-dev.

Comment: @fooledbyprimes -- I'm glad you got it to work... FWIW, I don't even remember writing this answer :-).  If you asked me how to do it today, I probably would have been stumped ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem when installing Cython.  If you go to your Python installation folder (assuming Python2.7 for this example), copy the C:\Python27\include directory and all of its contents to your home directory or the directory where you're running easy_install.  The "include" directory contains "python.h", which is the C header file for the compiler.

That being said, when I did that it eliminated that error, but still didn't work.

Bona sort.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work for me, i am on ubuntu and i do not have that include folder